# Can Schiff's reagent respond to hemiacetal?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, carbohydrates, organic-oxidation

Glucose responds with both Tollens' reagent $(\ce{AgNO3})$ and Fehling's solution $(\ce{CuSO4}).$ But it doesn't respond when treated with Schiff's reagent (*p*-rosaniline hydrochloride), the reason being that it exists in its pyranose structure, which has a hemiacetal in place of an aldehyde group.

So, does this mean that the Schiff's reagent does not react with hemiacetal, while both Tollens' and Fehling's do? Also, what about Benedict's solution? Can it serve as a test for hemiacetals?